# C++ file output duplicated

Tags: c++, file, input, output, duplicate-data

So basically I'm supposed to make a database like application in c++. The problem I have is when I try to save/read from the .txt files I've created. 
Classes definitions and output functions:

file:table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H__
#define TABLE_H__

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

class tableColumn
{
public:
    string colName;
    vector<string> tableCol;

    tableColumn() {};
    ~tableColumn() {};

    string getColName() { return colName; }
    void setColName(string);
    int getColSize() { return tableCol.size(); }

};


void tableColumn::setColName(string a)
{
    colName = a;
}

class tableMatrix
{
private:
    vector<tableColumn> table;
    string tableName;
public:
    tableMatrix() {};
    ~tableMatrix() {};

    string getTableName() { return tableName; }
    void setTableName(string);

    void saveToFile(string);
    void readFromFile(string);
};


void tableMatrix::saveToFile(string tableFileName)
{
    string aux;
    aux += tableFileName;
    aux += ".txt";

    ofstream out(aux.c_str());

    out << tableName << endl;
    out << table.at(1).getColSize() << endl;
    out << table.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)table.size(); i++)
    {
        out << table.at(i).colName<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)table.at(i).tableCol.size(); j++)
        {
            out << table.at(i).tableCol.at(j) << endl;
        }
    }
    out.close();
}

void tableMatrix::readFromFile(string tableFileName)
{
    string aux,element,space;
    int rows, cols;
    aux += tableFileName;
    aux += ".txt";

    ifstream in(aux.c_str());
    tableColumn auxc;

    getline(in, tableName);
    in >> rows;
    in >> cols;

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        in >> auxc.colName;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            in >> element;
            auxc.tableCol.push_back(element);
        }
        table.push_back(auxc);
        auxc.~tableColumn();
    }
    in.close();
}

#endif
```

file:database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H__
#define DATABASE_H__

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include"table.h"
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

class database
{
private:
    vector<tableMatrix> db;
public:
    database() {};
    ~database() {};

    void saveToFile();
    void readFromFile();
};


void database::saveToFile()
{

    ofstream out("tablenames.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)db.size(); i++)
    {
        out << db.at(i).getTableName() << endl;
    }
    out.close();

    vector<string> filenames;
    string aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)db.size(); i++)
    {
        aux = db.at(i).getTableName();
        filenames.push_back(aux);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)db.size(); i++)
    {
        db.at(i).saveToFile(filenames.at(i));
    }
}

void database::readFromFile()
{
    vector<string>filenames;
    string aux;
    ifstream in("tablenames.txt");
    tableMatrix auxt;

    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> aux;
        filenames.push_back(aux);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)filenames.size(); i++)
    {
        auxt.readFromFile(filenames.at(i));
        db.push_back(auxt);
    }
    in.close();
}

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include"database.h"
#include<sstream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    database A;
    A.readFromFile();
    A.saveToFile();

    return 0;
}
```

file : tablenames.txt

```
aaa
asa2
```

file : aaa.txt

```
aaa
3
2
col1
1
2
3
col2
4
5
6
```

file : asa2.txt

```
asa2
3
2
col1
1
2
3
col2
4
5
67
```

Basically I want to create a txt file with all table names (tablenames.txt) and then a txt file for each table with its name and column data. However when I try to run it, it's duplicating my last entry in tablenames.txt and it messes up my table data by adding additional columns and/or rows.

For example, tablenames.txt : ramdomname1, ramdomname2  becomes: ramdomname1,ramdomname2,ramdomname2.  Same deal with the other table files except that it does it on a larger scale (2 rows become 10 for example with duplicated/scrambled data).

Comment: And your question actually is?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and your actual question.

Comment: the question : what is the problem and how to "fix" it so that it does what I want it to do. It may be something obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: I'd recommend debugging your program, step through line by line and see what actually happens. Also possibly related [`while (!in.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: already done that and I can't see any problems.

Comment: @bf16: I get a whole screen full of compiler errors with your code, even after adding the necessary headers, `using namespace std` and rearranging the classes with dependencies between them. I tried isolating your problem with a smaller piece of code, but that worked fine. You need to post compilable code, or else we are left with guessing.

Comment: @bf16 it really means you need to try to compile that code, not just edit it and assume it's all right. Until you get something testable by people here, you likely won't get any answer. *Please* check your code with a compiler. And please don't get offended, it's usual practice here to downvote for that reason. It's nothing personal, you just need to fix your question.

Comment: Also: `auxc.~tableColumn();` ... That doesn't feel right at all.

Comment: You still need to provide `tableColumn::getColSize`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's just that I'm in a rush and the project is much bigger that what the problem is. Edited my post with full details. It should compile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is correct, but your input is wrong. You are not supposed to use `eof` like this. The idiomatic loop goes like this:

```
while (in >> aux)
{
    filenames.push_back(aux);
}
```

Look at thousands of past Stack Overflow questions and answers about using C++ streams in loops.

Let's have a look again at your original code:

```
while (!in.eof())
{
    in >> aux;
    filenames.push_back(aux);
}
```

What happens here is that <del>when EOF is encountered, no error has occurred yet</del>*the EOF flag is only set when a read operation actually encountered EOF*, so the loop condition still holds. The following call to `operator>>` *does* set the stream to <del>an error state</del>*EOF*, but it's too late. The operation leaves `aux` unmodified, i.e. with the same value as before. That unmodified value is then pushed back to the vector again. Afterwards, the loop condition is checked again and finally fails <del>(because the stream is in an error state)</del>.

In fact, for an even more robust approach, use the free-standing `std::getline` function and check every table name for correctness (e.g. not allowed characters, such as spaces or tabs):

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    if (isCorrect(line))
    {
        filenames.push_back(line);
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**: Some corrections on the explanation of original code.

Comment: and the `auxc.~tableColumn();` which makes the program segfault on my system, and the method definitions in headers, and the `using namespace` in headers, and perhaps the windowism at the beginning of `main.cpp` (that's ... ok maybe).

Comment: @didierc: In fact, the code could be improved a lot. I also dislike the C-style casts and the fact that no iterators are used for vector iteration.

Comment: yeah, I suppose so. Here's another way of writing the loop : `while (in >> aux && in.good()) { /* input check */ } // io error handling`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot the explanations,very helpful! I only have one more question since you mentioned it : what is wrong with using the casts ? If I remove those I get warnings ( that's the reason they're there in the first place).

Comment: @bf16: C-style casts only exist for C compatibility. In C++, you use one of several specific casts. In this case, `static_cast<int>(db.size())` will do fine. However, the idiomatic way to iterate over a container is with iterators, where the problem disappears entirely. Look here for a quick overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.2B.2B